# can't use parent method with child without ovrriding?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have this code:

```
public class Cardmo {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Decke poker = new Decke();

        poker.shuffle();

        PokerHand h1 = poker.deal();

        // problem : it prints a hole new deck and not the PokerHand h1 ??
        h1.print();
    }
}

class Carte {  

    int suit, rank;

    static String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
    static String[] ranks = { "narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
               "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    public Carte() {
        this.suit = 0;
        this.rank = 0;
    }

    public Carte(int suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }
}  

class Decke {  

    Carte[] cartes;

    public Decke(int n) {
        this.cartes = new Carte[n];
    }

    public Decke() {
    this.cartes = new Carte[52];

    int index = 0;
    for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
        for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
            this.cartes[index] = new Carte(suit, rank);
            index++;
        }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for(int i = 0; i < cartes.length; i++) {
            cartes[i].print();
        }
    }

    public int randomInt(int low, int high) {
       int x = (int)(Math.random() * (high-low) + low);
       return x; 
    }

    public void swapCartes(int i, int j) {
       Carte t = cartes[i];
       cartes[i] = cartes[j];
       cartes[j] = t;
    }  

    public void shuffle() {
        for(int i =0; i < cartes.length; i ++) {
           int swap = randomInt(i, cartes.length); 
           swapCartes(i, swap);
        }
    }

    public Decke subDecke(int low, int high) {
        Decke sub = new Decke(high - low + 1);

        for(int i = 0; i < sub.cartes.length; i++) {
            sub.cartes[i] = this.cartes[low + i];
        }

        return sub;
    }

    public PokerHand deal(int low) {
        Decke hand = this.subDecke(low, low + 4);
        PokerHand pokerhand = new PokerHand();

        for(int i = 0; i < hand.cartes.length; i++) {
            pokerhand.hand[i] = hand.cartes[i];
        }

        return pokerhand;
    }
}

class PokerHand extends Decke {  

    Carte[] hand = new Carte[5];

    public PokerHand(){}

    //why override?? why not use the parent one ??
   /* public void print(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            hand[i].print();
        }
    }*/
}
```

As you can see my problem is whenever I try to use the `print()` method from the parent it prints a hole new deck and not the hand h1. Also whenever I try to shuffle h1 using the parent method `h1.shuffle()`, it doesn't work as expected. Why?

How do I use the parent methods correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: `PokerHand` should **not** extend `Decke`. These two logical entities do not satisfy the "is-a" relationship (nor the "has-a" relationship for that matter) as they both will have drastically different behaviors. Make `PokerHand` its own class, one that *has* Cards, and again one that does not extend `Decke`. If you want both classes to share methods, then they may need a common abstract parent class (I doubt) or an interface (perhaps).

I would also use enums for Suits and Ranks, and rather than a print method, override each key class's `toString()` method. This way it will work as is within a println statement.

Also, I would use enums (a newer type of Java constants) for your Rank and Suit. These are the canonical use case for use of enums. Something like:

```
enum Suit {
    CLUBS("Clubs"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), HEARTS("Hearts"), SPADES("Spades");
    private String name;

    private Suit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

```
enum Rank {
    ACE("Ace"), TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4"), FIVE("5"), SIX("6"), SEVEN("7"), EIGHT("8"), 
    NINE("9"), TEN("10"), JACK("Jack"), QUEEN("Queen"), KING("King");

    private String name;

    private Rank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

And then Card would use the above in a "has-a" relationship:

```
class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Rank rank;
    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((rank == null) ? 0 : rank.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((suit == null) ? 0 : suit.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Card other = (Card) obj;
        if (rank != other.rank)
            return false;
        if (suit != other.suit)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card [suit=" + suit + ", rank=" + rank + "]";
    }

}
```

You might want to give Card an equals and hashCode method so that you can tell if two Cards are *functionally* equal.

Then Deck and Hand can actually share a super class, say called CardCollection as on deeper thought, I do see that they share behaviors:

```
// super class for both Deck and Hand
abstract class CardCollection implements Iterable<Card> {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    public Card discardCard() {
        // TODO: throw an exception if size is 0
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    public List<Card> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    public int size() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
        return cards.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CardCollection [cards=" + cards + "]";
    }

    public void clear() {
        cards.clear();
    }

}
```

```
class Deck extends CardCollection {
    public Deck() {
        renew();
    }

    public void renew() {
        clear();
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
                addCard(new Card(suit, rank));
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(getCards());
    }

    public Card deal() {
        return discardCard();
    }

}
```

```
class Hand extends CardCollection {

    public static final int HAND_SIZE = 5;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that `Decke` prints its array `cartes`, not the array `hand` introduced in the derived class. You should remove `hand` array altogether, and call `super(5)` from the constructor instead:

```
public PokerHand(){
    super(5);
}
```

While this will fix the printing, the overall logic of your program would remain broken.

Generally, you should avoid deriving `PokerHand` from `Decke`: derivation implies an is-a relationship, while in real life a poker hand is *not* a deck of cards.

If you would like to share code, make a shared base class, say, `AbstractCardCollection`, and use it as the base class for both `Decke` and `PokerHand`. Now the code for initializing, printing, and accessing elements of the collection of cards could be shared, while deck-specific and hand-specific functionality could be implemented separately.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Absolutely not. I was in the process of typing up a suggestion of how to fix this, while still sharing some related code.